# dynamically adding multiple fragments to my activity layout

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout with no child views

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


</LinearLayout>
```

and i want to dynamically add one fragment or two fragments as per requirements in it.
i am aware of adding one fragment to it but how can i add two to fragments dynamically to it.
I have two fragments and within each fragment i write the following oncreateview

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return v; 
    }
```

i am trying to add using the following code but the second fragment is coming over the first one.

```
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        frag1 f=new frag1();
        frag2 ff=new frag2();


        ft.add(android.R.id.content, f);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, ff);

        ft.commit();
```

kindly update how this can be done.
thanks

Comment: +1 I am also looking for the answer to this question... It seems such an important question and yet I am unable to find an answer :/ - dynamically adding two fragments in an activity layout - that seems like pretty standard stuff to me but it isn't covered anywhere afaik.

Comment: Update to this is that you cannot add two to android.R.id.content but to a Layout such as LinearLayout or anyother with a id as below: if id one is the id of the viewgroup then ft.add(R.id.one,f,"one");ft.add(R.id.one,ff,"two"); ft.commit(); kindly try this and update

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me :) ! Actually by now I found a way to host two fragments in one Activity. All that needs to be done is to have two containers in the layout - one for each fragment and then setting a weight on them. Like: First Container gets 30% of the space, second container get's 70% of the space. If you need more details do let me know. Most of it is setup in the layout file, so and you'd change your fragment transaction to add each to the id of its target container.

Comment: That actually is not the problem. what happens if you actually dont know whether you will be adding one fragment or two .that is to be decided at runtime rather than at complile time . in that case you cannot create two LayoutManagers earlier itself

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. If you decide on the number of fragments based on the layout --> simply use different layout files. If you randomly decide on the number of fragments you display, add as many containers as you need at max (like 3 containers if you maximum gonna show 3 fragments), don't set their weight and make them invisible(View.GONE) until you actually need them. Another option is to pick a different activity based on how many fragments you are going to show. Let me know if you need a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This shoudl do the Trick:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    frag1 f=new frag1();
    frag2 ff=new frag2();
    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ft.add(android.R.id.content, f).commit();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction(); // this line might be unnescessary
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, ff).commit();
```

Comment: it is the same that i am already writing but it is not working.

Comment: It should work if you set your LayoutParams of your main LinearLayout to wrap_content.